# PHP error al registrar datos en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando registrar esta cantidad de productos en una base de datos de `MySQL`, he verificado pero no logro dar con el error al momento de registrarlo, tampoco me arroja error en alguna linea. Solo salta el error que tengo en el `if`. A continuación esta el `.php` con el que registro.

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$fecha=$_POST["fecha"];
$semipura = $_POST["semipura"];
$pura_extra = $_POST["pura_extra"];
$picada = $_POST["picada"];
$pura_normal = $_POST["pura_normal"];
$pura_8020 = $_POST["pura_8020"];
$pura_100 = $_POST["pura_100"];
$libreada_500gr = $_POST["libreada_500gr"];
$libreada_250gr = $_POST["libreada_250gr"];
$libreada_125gr = $_POST["libreada_125gr"];
$crema_500gr = $_POST["crema_500gr"];
$crema_250gr = $_POST["crema_250gr"];
$crema_125gr = $_POST["crema_125gr"];
$suero_220gr = $_POST["suero_220gr"];
$andiponque = $_POST["andiponque"];
$hojaldre = $_POST["hojaldre"];
$oleofree = $_POST["oleofree"];
$m_8020 = $_POST["m_8020"];
$artepan = $_POST["artepan"];
$m_de_cerdo = $_POST["m_de_cerdo"];
$roscon = $_POST["roscon"];
$miloja = $_POST["miloja"];
$caneca = $_POST["caneca"];
$piña_kl = $_POST["piña_kl"];
$piña_lb = $_POST["piña_lb"];
$piña_5lb = $_POST["piña_5lb"];
$breva = $_POST["breva"];
$veleño = $_POST["veleño"];
$coberturas = $_POST["coberturas"];
$grajeas = $_POST["grajeas"];
$bocadillo = $_POST["bocadillo"];
$lonja = $_POST["lonja"];
$esencia = $_POST["esencia"];
$e_garrafa = $_POST["e_garrafa"];
$coco_angel = $_POST["coco_angel"];
$coco_azucarado = $_POST["coco_azucarado"];
$fruta = $_POST["fruta"];
$polvo_hornear = $_POST["polvo_hornear"];
$azucar_pulverizada = $_POST["azucar_pulverizada"];

$insertar = "INSERT into productos(fecha, semipura,pura_extra,picada, pura_normal, pura_8020, pura_100, libreada_500gr, libreada_250gr,
                                    libreada_125gr, crema_500gr, crema_250gr, crema_125gr, suero_220gr, andiponque, hojaldre, oleofree, m_8020,
                                    artepan, m_de_cerdo, aceite_bidon, roscon, miloja, caneca, piña_kl, piña_lb, piña_5lb, breva, veleño, coberturas,
                                    grajeas, bocadillo, lonja, esencia, e_garrafa, coco_angel, coco_azucarado, fruta, polvo_hornear, azucar_pulverizada)
                                    VALUES ('$fecha','$semipura', '$pura_extra', '$picada', '$pura_normal', '$pura_8020', '$pura_100', '$libreada_500gr',
                                    '$libreada_250gr', '$libreada_125gr', '$crema_500gr', '$crema_250gr', '$crema_125gr', '$suero_220gr', '$andiponque',
                                    '$hojaldre', '$oleofree', '$m_8020', '$artepan', '$m_de_cerdo', '$roscon', '$miloja', '$caneca', '$piña_kl', '$piña_lb',
                                    $piña_5lb, $breva, $veleño, $coberturas, $grajeas, $bocadillo, $lonja, $esencia, $e_garrafa, $coco_angel, 
                                    '$coco_azucarado','$fruta', '$polvo_hornear','$azucar_pulverizada')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

if(!$resultado){
    echo 'error al registrar';
} else{
    'bien';
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Este es el `.php` del formulario por medio de este ingreso la cantidad de productos que quiero. No se si sea un error con el orden con el que llame las variables o si es un error de campos en la base de datos, aunque no creo ya que todos los campos los tengo de `"number"` excepto el de fecha lo tengo como `"date"`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialize">
    <title>Inventarios.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">


<body>
    <?php
    
    $fecha_actual=date("d-m-Y");
    ?>
    <form action="registrar.php" method="POST">
        <center>
            <input type="submit" class="botons" value="Volver atrás" onclick="history.back()"
                style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10 pt">
        </center>
        <section class="form-register">
            <h4>INVENTARIO DIARIO.</h4>
            <td>Fecha:</td>
            <td><input class="controls" type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" placeholder="Fecha" value="<?= $fecha_actual?>"></td>
            <td>
                <h2>Arrobaje:</h2>
            </td>
            <section id="arroba">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Semipura:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="semipura" id="semipura" placeholder="Semipura">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pura Extra:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="pura_extra" id="pura_extra" placeholder="Pura Extra">
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Picada:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="picada" id="picada" placeholder="Picada"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pura Normal:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="pura_normal" id="pura_normal" placeholder="Pura Normal">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pura 80-20:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="pura_8020" id="pura_8020" placeholder="Pura 80-20">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pura 100%:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="pura_100" id="pura_100" placeholder="Pura 100%">
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>

            </section>
            <table>
                <td><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Arrobaje Mostrar" onclick="Mostrar()"></td>
                <td><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Arrobaje Ocultar" onclick="Ocultar()"></td>
            </table>
            <label>
                <h2>Mantequilla:</h2>
            </label>
            <section id="mant">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Libreada 500gr:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="libreada_500gr" id="libreada_500gr" placeholder="500gr"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Libreada 250 gr:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="libreada_250gr" id="libreada_250gr" placeholder="250gr"></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Libreada 125gr:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="libreada_125gr" id="libreada_125gr" placeholder="125gr"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
            <table>
                <td><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Mantequilla Mostrar" onclick="Mostrar1()"></td>
                <td><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Mantequilla Ocultar" onclick="Ocultar1()"></td>
            </table>
            <label>
                <h2>Crema/Suero:</h2>
            </label>
            <section id="crema">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Crema de leche 500gr:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="crema_500gr" id="crema_500gr" placeholder="500gr"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Crema de leche 250 gr:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="crema_250gr" id="crema_250gr" placeholder="250gr"></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Crema de leche 125gr:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="crema_125gr" id="crema_125gr" placeholder="125gr"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Suero Costeño 220gr:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="suero_220gr" id="suero_220gr" placeholder="220gr"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
            <table>
                <td><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Crema/Suero Mostrar" onclick="Mostrar2()"></td>
                <td><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Crema/Suero Ocultar" onclick="Ocultar2()"></td>
            </table>
            <label>
                <h2>Margarinas:</h2>
            </label>
            <section id="marg">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Andiponque:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="andiponque" id="andiponque" placeholder="Andiponque">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Andihojaldre:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="hojaldre" id="hojaldre"
                                placeholder="Andihojaldre"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>OleoFree:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="oleofree" id="oleofree" placeholder="OleoFree">
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>80-20:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="m_8020" id="m_8020" placeholder="80-20"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ArtePan:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="artepan" id="artepan" placeholder="ArtePan">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
            <table>
                <td><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Margarinas Mostrar" onclick="Mostrar3()"></td>
                <td><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Margarinas Ocultar" onclick="Ocultar3()"></td>
            </table>
            <label>
                <h2>Arandelas:</h2>
            </label>
            <section id="aran">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Manteca de cerdo:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="m_de_cerdo" id="m_de_cerdo"
                                placeholder="Manteca de cerdo"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Arequipe Roscon:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="roscon" id="roscon"
                                placeholder="Arequipe Roscon"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Arequipe Miloja:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="miloja" id="miloja"
                                placeholder="Arequipe Miloja"></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Caneca Arequipe:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="caneca" id="caneca"
                                placeholder="Caneca Arequipe"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Piña Kilo:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="piña_kl" id="piña_kl" placeholder="Piña Kilo">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Piña Libra:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="piña_lb" id="piña_lb" placeholder="Piña Libra">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Piña 5 Lbs:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="piña_5lb" id="piña_5lb" placeholder="Piña 5 Lbs">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Breva:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="breva" id="breva" placeholder="Breva"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Veleño:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="veleño" id="veleño" placeholder="Veleño"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Coberturas:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="coberturas" id="coberturas" placeholder="Coberturas">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Grajeas:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="grajeas" id="grajeas" placeholder="Grajeas">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bocadillo 1/2@:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="bocadillo" id="bocadillo"
                                placeholder="Bocadillo 1/2@"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lonja:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="lonja" id="lonja" placeholder="Lonja"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Esencia:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="esencia" id="esencia" placeholder="Esencia">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Esencia Garrafa:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="e_garrafa" id="e_garrafa"
                                placeholder="Esencia Garrafa"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Coco Angel:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="coco_angel" id="coco_angel" placeholder="Coco Angel">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Coco Azucarado:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="coco_azucarado" id="coco_azucarado"
                                placeholder="Coco Azucarado"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fruta 2.5:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="fruta" id="fruta" placeholder="Fruta 2.5">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Polvo Hornear:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="polvo_hornear" id="polvo_hornear"
                                placeholder="Polvo Hornear"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Azucar Pulverizada:</td>
                        <td><input class="controls" type="number" name="azucar_pulverizada" id="azucar_pulverizada"
                                placeholder="Azucar Pulverizada"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
            <table>
                <td><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Arandelas Mostrar" onclick="Mostrar4()"></td>
                <td><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Arandelas Ocultar" onclick="Ocultar4()"></td>
            </table>


            <center>
                <td>
                <td><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Registrar Inventario" onclick=""></td>
                </td>
            </center>



    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Mostrar() {
        document.getElementById("arroba").style.display = "block";
    }
    function Ocultar() {
        document.getElementById("arroba").style.display = "none";
    }
    function Mostrar1() {
        document.getElementById("mant").style.display = "block";
    }
    function Ocultar1() {
        document.getElementById("mant").style.display = "none";
    }
    function Mostrar2() {
        document.getElementById("crema").style.display = "block";
    }
    function Ocultar2() {
        document.getElementById("crema").style.display = "none";
    }
    function Mostrar3() {
        document.getElementById("marg").style.display = "block";
    }
    function Ocultar3() {
        document.getElementById("marg").style.display = "none";
    }
    function Mostrar4() {
        document.getElementById("aran").style.display = "block";
    }
    function Ocultar4() {
        document.getElementById("aran").style.display = "none";
    }


</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Saludos. Prueba usando `mysqli_connect_error` o `mysqli_error` para ver si reporta el error (mira su uso en https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php ).

Comment: Gracias amigo, si me mostró el error que tenia

Comment: Me salio este error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" sabes que puede ser?

Comment: Es probable que el error se deba a que no estas escapando correctamente las variables. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el mensaje de error: *`Column count doesn't match value count at row ...`*  ocurre cuando la cantidad de columnas del insert y las indicadas en la parte de `VALUES` no coincide.

Si escribes la instrucción identada, y las columnas agrupadas de `10` en `10` podrás ver rápidamente el error.

Esta es la consulta identadada:

```
INSERT into productos
    (
        fecha, 
        semipura,
        pura_extra,
        picada, 
        pura_normal, 
        pura_8020, 
        pura_100, 
        libreada_500gr, 
        libreada_250gr,
        libreada_125gr, 
        
        crema_500gr, 
        crema_250gr, 
        crema_125gr, 
        suero_220gr, 
        andiponque, 
        hojaldre, 
        oleofree, 
        m_8020,
        artepan, 
        m_de_cerdo, 
        
        aceite_bidon, -- no se está pasando VALUE para esta columna
        roscon, 
        miloja, 
        caneca, 
        piña_kl, 
        piña_lb, 
        piña_5lb, 
        breva, 
        veleño, 
        coberturas,
        
        grajeas, 
        bocadillo, 
        lonja, 
        esencia, 
        e_garrafa, 
        coco_angel, 
        coco_azucarado, 
        fruta, 
        polvo_hornear, 
        azucar_pulverizada
    )
    VALUES 
    (
        '$fecha',
        '$semipura', 
        '$pura_extra', 
        '$picada', 
        '$pura_normal', 
        '$pura_8020', 
        '$pura_100', 
        '$libreada_500gr',
        '$libreada_250gr',      
        '$libreada_125gr', 
        
        '$crema_500gr', 
        '$crema_250gr', 
        '$crema_125gr', 
        '$suero_220gr', 
        '$andiponque',
        '$hojaldre', 
        '$oleofree', 
        '$m_8020', 
        '$artepan', 
        '$m_de_cerdo', 
        
        -- aquí falta valor para columna aceite_bidon
        '$roscon', 
        '$miloja', 
        '$caneca', 
        '$piña_kl', 
        '$piña_lb',
        $piña_5lb, 
        $breva, 
        $veleño, 
        $coberturas, 
        
        $grajeas, 
        $bocadillo, 
        $lonja, 
        $esencia, 
        $e_garrafa, 
        $coco_angel,
        '$coco_azucarado',
        '$fruta', 
        '$polvo_hornear',
        '$azucar_pulverizada'
    )
```

Observa ahora el tercer grupo de diez, en la parte de `VALUES`, allí no estás pasando datos para la columna `aceite_bidon`. En el código tampoco se ve ningún dato que se recupere de `$_POST` para esa columna.

Otro posible problema es que en algunos `VALUE` no estás usando comillas simples, no sé si en la tabla esos valores son numéricos y por eso omitiste las comillas simples ¿? Tal es el caso de los valores `$piña_5lb` y otros en la segunda mitad de la tercera decena de valores, y los primeros valores de la cuarta decena, como  `$grajeas`  y otros.

Corrigiendo eso, el código debería funciona, salvo otros errores.

---

### Recomendaciones

Como recomendación, considera aplicar el uso de consultas preparadas, pues tu código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

También, viendo la naturaleza del `INSERT` es probable que haga falta una normalización profunda en tu modelo de datos, pero eso ya sobrepasa el alcance de esta pregunta.